# IE table background bug

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

I have a table with background image shown in my site. The FF and chrome looks normal but not in IE. The background image seems to shift and generate wired result. I was wondering if anyone here can help me out on this one. Please see attached [picture](http://www.popslinger.org/iebug.JPG). Thanks for the help.

```
<section>
some html....

<form action="http://localhost/jobSearch/add_project/validate" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>ADD NEW PROJECT</legend>
      <label>Parcel</label>
      <input type="text" name="parcel" value="">
      <label>Lot Number</label>
      <input type="text" name="lot_number" value="">
      <label>Block</label>
      <input type="text" name="block" value="">
      <label>Subdivision</label>
      <input type="text" name="subdivision_name" value="">
      <label>Section/Phase</label>
      <input type="text" name="section_phase" value="">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Project" id="submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>

more html.....
</section>
```

CSS:

```
form {
    display: block;
}

form fieldset {
    font: bold 1.1em helvetica;
}

form label{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:140px;
    font:bold 1.1em Helvetica;
    margin:5px;
}

fieldset{
    color:black;
    font:bold 1.2em Helvertica;
    width:400px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border:1px solid grey;
    background:url('../images/background.jpg');
}

form input {
    font-size: .9em;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    border: solid 1px #AACFE4;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
}

form #submit {
    cursor: pointer;
    font: bold 1em Helvetica;
    padding: 4px 2px;
    border: solid 1px #AACFE4;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 100px;
}​
```

Comment: Can you provide an example via http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net? Also, when using prefixes, be sure to use all other browser vendor prefixes as well. In the case of `border-radius`, you want to include the non-prefixed version too.

Comment: @JonathanSampson sure, hope it helps. http://jsfiddle.net/VV8UZ/

Comment: Which version of IE did you test in? I tested http://jsfiddle.net/VV8UZ/1/ in IE7 through IE10 and I cannot repeat the error. Are you using a valid doctype? Have you checked your markup for errors?

Comment: I use IE8 to test. I have html5 doctype which is 
<!DOCTYPE html>. I am not sure how to repeat the errors on jsfiddle. I will do the hard way by cutting and pasting codes to find the errors and post more info if I need more help. Thanks for the help Jonathan. +1

Comment: Do you have server on which you could host the page temporarily?

Comment: yes I do. Please see http://www.popslinger.org/projectStatus/. The login page should show you the error. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tags are not properly nested. You open with `<form>`, but close with `</fieldset>`. You need to swap the locations of the closing tags in the example below to correct the nesting issue.

```
<form ...>
  <fieldset>
<!-- content removed -->
  </form>
</fieldset>
```